# Connect signal r clients to a PHP server for real time communication

Tags: php, signalr

We are working on a car booking app to make it work with a PHP server. the mobile app is already using Signal R for real-time communication with a .NET server. we want to modify the code to connect to our PHP server.

My question is how can I connect this signal R code to communicate to a PHP server? How signal R will Work with a PHP server? Any solution for that?

Our primary aim is to make it work with signal R instead of switching to other solutions. Still, I would appreciate your recommendations.

Here is Java code that needs to communicate with PHP server

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using MyBuddyRide_APIs.Models;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SortApp.ChatService;
using MyBuddyRide_APIs.Helper_Snippets;
using System.Data.Entity;
using MyBuddyRide_APIs.Enums;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyBuddyRide_APIs.ChatService
{
    [HubName("brHub")]
    public class PrivateChatHub : Hub
    {
        private MBRDbContext db = new MBRDbContext();

        #region Internal Calls
        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public override Task OnReconnected()
        {
            return base.OnReconnected();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
            string connectionId = this.Context.ConnectionId;
            User user = this.db.Users.Where(s => s.ConnectionId == connectionId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
            {
                user.ConnectionId = null;
                this.db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                var driver = this.db.Driver.Where(s => s.ConnectionId == connectionId).FirstOrDefault();
                if (driver != null)
                {
                    //get all the active vehicles, if any vehicle is not in progress, set vehicles status offiline
                    var veh = db.Vechicles.Where(s => s.Status == DriverStatus.InProgress || s.Status == DriverStatus.OnLine).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (veh != null)
                    {
                        if (veh.Status == DriverStatus.OnLine)
                        {
                            veh.Status = DriverStatus.OffLine;
                            RemoveDriver(driver.DriverId);
                        }
                    }

                    driver.ConnectionId = null;
                    this.db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Rider Calls
        [HubMethodName("goOnlineUser")]
        public string GoOnlineUser(int userId)
        {
            try
            {
                if (userId > 0)
                {
                    string connectionId = this.Context.ConnectionId;
                    User user = this.db.Users.Where(s => s.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        user.ConnectionId = connectionId;
                        db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new HubResponse());
                    }
                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new HubResponse()
                    {
                        status = false,
                        message = "unable to update status"
                    });
                }
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                {
                    status = false,
                    message = "invalid userId"
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                {
                    status = false,
                    message = ("some error occured!: " + ex.Message),
                    data = (object)ex.InnerException
                });
            }
        }

        [HubMethodName("goOfflineRider")]
        public string GoOfflineRider(long riderId, string token)
        {
            try
            {
                if (riderId > 0)
                {
                    var user = this.db.Users.Where(s => s.UserId == riderId).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        user.ConnectionId = null;
                        db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

                        db.SaveChanges();

                        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new HubResponse());
                    }
                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new HubResponse()
                    {
                        status = false,
                        message = "unable to update status"
                    });
                }
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                {
                    status = false,
                    message = "invalid userId"
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                {
                    status = false,
                    message = ("some error occured!: " + ex.Message),
                    data = (object)ex.InnerException
                });
            }
        }

        [HubMethodName("getNearbyDriver")]
        public string GetNearbyDriver(long userId, string token)
        {
            try
            {
                if (userId > 0 && token != null)
                {
                    var user = db.Users.Where(s => s.UserId == userId && s.Token == token).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        //get all the online drivers's location
                        var locations = db.Driver.Where(s => !s.InRide && s.ConnectionId != null && s.Vehicles.Where(e => e.Status == DriverStatus.OnLine).FirstOrDefault() != null).Select(s => new DriverLocationUpdate
                        {
                            bearing = s.Bearing,
                            driverId = s.DriverId,
                            lat = s.Latitude,
                            lon = s.Longitude
                        }).ToList();

                        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new HubResponse()
                        {
                            data = locations
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                        {
                            status = false,
                            message = "invalid User"
                        });
                    }
                }
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                {
                    status = false,
                    message = "invalid userId"
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                {
                    status = false,
                    message = ("some error occured!: " + ex.Message),
                    data = (object)ex.InnerException
                });
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Driver Calls
        [HubMethodName("goOnlineDriver")]
        public string GoOnlineDriver(long driverId, int vehicleId = 0)
        {
            try
            {
                if (driverId > 0)
                {
                    string connectionId = this.Context.ConnectionId;
                    var user = this.db.Driver.Where(s => s.DriverId == driverId).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        user.ConnectionId = connectionId;
                        db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        if (vehicleId > 0)
                        {
                            //check if any vehicle was not in progress, then make it online
                            var veh = db.Vechicles.Where(s => s.VehicleId == vehicleId && s.Status != DriverStatus.InProgress).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (veh != null)
                            {
                                veh.Status = DriverStatus.OnLine;
                            }
                        }
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new HubResponse());
                    }
                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new HubResponse()
                    {
                        status = false,
                        message = "unable to update status"
                    });
                }
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                {
                    status = false,
                    message = "invalid userId"
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                {
                    status = false,
                    message = ("some error occured!: " + ex.Message),
                    data = (object)ex.InnerException
                });
            }
        }

        [HubMethodName("updateLocation")]
        public string UpdateDriverLocation(long driverId, int vehicleId, double latitude = 0.0, double longitude = 0.0, double bearing = 0.0)
        {
            try
            {
                if (driverId > 0 && vehicleId > 0)
                {
                    var user = this.db.Driver.Where(s => s.DriverId == driverId && s.Vehicles.Where(x=>x.VehicleId == vehicleId).FirstOrDefault()!=null).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        user.Latitude = latitude;
                        user.Longitude = longitude;
                        user.Bearing = bearing;
                        db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

                        db.SaveChanges();

                        //notify all the users who are not in ride

                        NewDriverLocation(new DriverLocationUpdate
                        {
                            driverId = user.DriverId,
                            bearing = bearing,
                            lat = latitude,
                            lon = longitude
                        });

                        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new HubResponse());
                    }
                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new HubResponse()
                    {
                        status = false,
                        message = "unable to update status"
                    });
                }
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                {
                    status = false,
                    message = "invalid userId"
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                {
                    status = false,
                    message = ("some error occured!: " + ex.Message),
                    data = (object)ex.InnerException
                });
            }
        }

        [HubMethodName("goOfflineDriver")]
        public string GoOfflineDriver(long driverId, int vehicleId = 0)
        {
            try
            {
                if (driverId > 0)
                {
                    var user = this.db.Driver.Where(s => s.DriverId == driverId).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        user.ConnectionId = null;
                        db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;

                        if (vehicleId > 0)
                        {
                            //put the online vehicle offline
                            var veh = db.Vechicles.Where(s => s.VehicleId == vehicleId && s.Status == DriverStatus.OnLine).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (veh != null)
                            {
                                veh.Status = DriverStatus.OffLine;
                                RemoveDriver(driverId);
                            }
                        }

                        db.SaveChanges();

                        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new HubResponse());
                    }
                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new HubResponse()
                    {
                        status = false,
                        message = "unable to update status"
                    });
                }
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                {
                    status = false,
                    message = "invalid userId"
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                {
                    status = false,
                    message = ("some error occured!: " + ex.Message),
                    data = (object)ex.InnerException
                });
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Chat Calls
        [HubMethodName("getAllChats")]
        public string GetAllChats(int rideId)
        {
            try
            {
                var ride = db.Rides.Where(s => s.RideId == rideId).FirstOrDefault();

                if (ride == null)
                {
                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new HubResponse()
                    {
                        status = false,
                        message = "Unknows Ride!"
                    });
                }

                var resp = db.PrivateChats.AsNoTracking().Where(e => e.Ride.RideId == rideId).AsEnumerable().Select(s => new HubChatMessage
                {
                    message = s.Message,
                    rideId = rideId,
                    datetime = s.Time.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"),
                    sender = s.Sender
                }).ToList();
                HubResponse hubResponse = new HubResponse
                {
                    data = resp
                };
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hubResponse);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                {
                    status = false,
                    message = ("some error occured!: " + ex.Message),
                    data = (object)ex.InnerException
                });
            }
        }

        [HubMethodName("sendMessage")]
        public string SendMessage(int rideId, string sender, string message, string datetime)
        {
            try
            {
                var ride = db.Rides.Include("User").Include("Driver").Where(s => s.RideId == rideId).FirstOrDefault();
                if (ride != null)
                {
                    if (ride.User == null || ride.Driver == null)
                    {
                        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                        {
                            status = false,
                            message = "Invalid Ride Session!"
                        });
                    }

                    //receiver
                    string connectionId = null;

                    if (sender == "rider")
                    {
                        connectionId = ride.Driver.ConnectionId;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        connectionId = ride.User.ConnectionId;
                    }

                    var newMessage = new HubChatMessage
                    {
                        datetime = datetime,
                        message = message,
                        sender = sender,
                        rideId = rideId
                    };

                    var privateChatMessage = new PrivateChatMessage
                    {
                        Message = message,
                        Time = DateTime.ParseExact(datetime, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        Sender = sender,
                        Ride = ride
                    };
                    db.PrivateChats.Add(privateChatMessage);

                    db.SaveChanges();

                    if (connectionId != null)
                    {
                        //call client side method.s
                        NewMessage(connectionId, newMessage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (sender != "rider")
                        {
                            //send push
                            SendPushNotifications push = new SendPushNotifications();
                            push.NotifyPerson(ride.User.UserId, message, "New Message", newMessage);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //send push
                            SendPushNotifications push = new SendPushNotifications();
                            push.NotifyDriver(ride.Driver.DriverId, message, "New Message", newMessage);
                        }
                    }

                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                    {
                        message = "message sent"
                    });
                }
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                {
                    status = false,
                    message = "invalid message"
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                {
                    status = false,
                    message = ("some error occured!: " + ex.Message),
                    data = (object)ex.InnerException
                });
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Ride Session
        [HubMethodName("updateCaptainLocation")] //Captain's location who accepted the request will sync his location to rider
        public string UpdateCaptainLocation(long rideId, double latitude = 0.0, double longitude = 0.0, double bearing = 0.0)
        {
            try
            {
                if (rideId > 0)
                {
                    var userConnId = db.Rides.Where(s => s.RideId == rideId).Select(s => new
                    {
                        s.Driver.DriverId,
                        s.User.ConnectionId
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (userConnId != null)
                    {
                        if (userConnId.ConnectionId != null)
                        {
                            //notify rider
                            NewCaptianLocation(userConnId.ConnectionId, new DriverLocationUpdate
                            {
                                driverId = userConnId.DriverId,
                                bearing = bearing,
                                lat = latitude,
                                lon = longitude
                            });
                        }
                        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new HubResponse());
                    }
                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new HubResponse()
                    {
                        status = false,
                        message = "unable to update status"
                    });
                }
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                {
                    status = false,
                    message = "invalid userId"
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject((object)new HubResponse()
                {
                    status = false,
                    message = ("some error occured!: " + ex.Message),
                    data = (object)ex.InnerException
                });
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Client Side Invocations

        private void NewMessage(string connectionId, HubChatMessage newMessage)
        {
            Clients.Client(connectionId).newMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newMessage));
        }
        //notify all the online users
        private void NewDriverLocation(DriverLocationUpdate location)
        {
            var onlineUsers = db.Users.Where(s => s.ConnectionId != null && !s.InRide).Select(s => s.ConnectionId).ToList();
            if (onlineUsers.Count > 0)
            {
                Clients.Clients(onlineUsers).newDriverLocation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(location));
            }
        }

        //notify the rider about his captian location. 
        private void NewCaptianLocation(string riderConnectionId, DriverLocationUpdate location)
        {
            Clients.Client(riderConnectionId).newCaptainLocation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(location));
        }

        //notify users to remove driver from map as he's offline.
        private void RemoveDriver(long driverId)
        {
            var onlineUsers = db.Users.Where(s => s.ConnectionId != null && !s.InRide).Select(s => s.ConnectionId).ToList();
            if (onlineUsers.Count > 0)
            {
                Clients.Clients(onlineUsers).removeDriver(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    driverId = driverId
                }
                ));
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Controller Helpers
        /// <summary>
        /// Helper function for Ride controller to remove the driver who have accepted the ride request
        /// This pirtucular driver should not send his location to all users except the one who have requested him.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="driverId"></param>
        /// <param name="onlineUsers"></param>
        public static void RemoveDriverWhenInRide(long driverId,List<string> onlineUsers)
        {
            if (onlineUsers.Count > 0)
            {
                var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PrivateChatHub>();
                hub.Clients.Clients(onlineUsers).removeDriver(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
                {
                    driverId = driverId
                }
                ));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not write some code for that? What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: PHP Server? Do you mean an API written in PHP or a websocket service? I worry you have to be more specific.

Comment: I am new to socket programing and have no idea how would i perform realtime tasks like search nearby connected drivers etc. can any real time php library like ratchat etc be used to connect to clients which are programmed in signal R?

Comment: You would need to write your own SignalR server in PHP if you want the clients to connect to it. There is a protocol that the server and clients follow, its documented here https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/SignalR/docs/specs